# How to determine the name of an Impala object corresponds to a view

Tags: impala

Is there a way in Impala to determine whether an object name returned by [SHOW TABLES](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_show.html) corresponds to a table or a view since:

- this statement only return the object names, without their type
- [SHOW CREATE VIEW](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_show.html#show_create_view) is just an alias for [SHOW CREATE TABLE](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_show.html#show_create_table) (same result, no view/table distinction)
- [DESCRIBE](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_describe.html) does not give any clue about the type of the item

Ideally I'd like to list all the tables + views and their types using a single operation, not one to retrieve the tables + views and then another call for each name to determine the type of the object.

(please note the question is about Impala, not Hive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `describe formatted` to know the type of an object

```sql
impala-shell> CREATE TABLE table2(
  id INT,
  name STRING
);

impala-shell> CREATE VIEW view2 AS SELECT * FROM table2;

impala-shell> DESCRIBE FORMATTED table2;

+------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
| name                         | type                                                               | comment              |
+------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+
| Retention:                   | 0                                                                  | NULL                 |
| Location:                    | hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/test.db/table2 | NULL                 |
| Table Type:                  | MANAGED_TABLE                                                      | NULL                 |
+------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------+

impala-shell> DESCRIBE FORMATTED view2;

+------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------+
| name                         | type                          | comment              |
+------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------+
| Protect Mode:                | None                          | NULL                 |
| Retention:                   | 0                             | NULL                 |
| Table Type:                  | VIRTUAL_VIEW                  | NULL                 |
| Table Parameters:            | NULL                          | NULL                 |
|                              | transient_lastDdlTime         | 1601632695           |
|                              | NULL                          | NULL                 |
| # Storage Information        | NULL                          | NULL                 |

+------------------------------+-------------------------------+----------------------+
```

In the case of the table type is `Table Type: MANAGED_TABLE` and for the view is `Table Type: VIRTUAL_VIEW`

Other way is querying `metastore database` (if you can) to know about metadata in Impala(or Hive)

```sql
mysql> use metastore;
mysql> select * from TBLS;
+--------+-------------+-------+------------------+-----------+-----------+-------+----------+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+----------------+
| TBL_ID | CREATE_TIME | DB_ID | LAST_ACCESS_TIME | OWNER     | RETENTION | SD_ID | TBL_NAME | TBL_TYPE      | VIEW_EXPANDED_TEXT                                         | VIEW_ORIGINAL_TEXT        | LINK_TARGET_ID |
+--------+-------------+-------+------------------+-----------+-----------+-------+----------+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+----------------+
|   9651 |  1601631971 |  9331 |                0 | anonymous |         0 | 27996 | table1   | MANAGED_TABLE | NULL                                                       | NULL                      |           NULL |
|   9652 |  1601632121 |  9331 |                0 | anonymous |         0 | 27997 | view1    | VIRTUAL_VIEW  | SELECT `table1`.`id`, `table1`.`name` FROM `test`.`table1` | SELECT * FROM table1      |           NULL |
|   9653 |  1601632676 |  9331 |                0 | cloudera  |         0 | 27998 | table2   | MANAGED_TABLE | NULL                                                       | NULL                      |           NULL |
|   9654 |  1601632695 |  9331 |                0 | cloudera  |         0 | 27999 | view2    | VIRTUAL_VIEW  | SELECT * FROM test.table2                                  | SELECT * FROM test.table2 |           NULL |
+--------+-------------+-------+------------------+-----------+-----------+-------+----------+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't have access to the metastore database. Ideally, I'd like to avoid having to execute another query for each object name (question updated) but I don't think it's possible with Impala alone.

Comment: BTW I'm starting to think it's not possible to retrieve all the objects type in a single command singe Hue does not display the view icon before the view is actually accessed

Comment: Hi @vc74, you could do something like that via scpript with impala-shell. Making up a script and running it via impala-shell and writing the output in a file.

Comment: script.sql ==> `USE test;
DESCRIBE FORMATTED table1;
DESCRIBE FORMATTED table2;
DESCRIBE FORMATTED view1;
DESCRIBE FORMATTED view2;`  shell command ==> `$ impala-shell -f script.sql --delimited --output_delimiter='\t' -o results.txt`

Comment: But that would require executing a command for each table/view which is what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: not exactly what I was looking for but I think it's the best we can do, thanks for your help

Comment: Hi @vc74 you're welcome. Yeah! I know, I've done some research on my own and thinking about this from time to time and I've done some trials but I got nothing.